# Question is not fully loaded on iPad

Tags: bug, ios-app

[Here is the question](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/231/168)

[image]

As you can see, the image and the rest of the question are not fully loaded.

- App Version: 1.4.2.2
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.1 (Build 13E238)

Comment: Is this because of caching? After posting this bug, the problem is not showing anymore.

Comment: Maybe just a laggy connection.

Comment: But at that time, I returned and came back but it still happened. I'm not sure if it was caching or lagging. Does the app use cache like websites? I don't know much about this.

Comment: I don't think it's using caching, and even so, pretty sure it won't cache partial data anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I have transferred your comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is not likely to have cache, and even so it's not likely to only save partial data. It seems to be a laggy connection.