# Edit via iOS app - "This suggested edit changes too much"

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app

When I wanted to edit the title of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279210/question-is-not-fully-load-in-ipad) on the iOS app, I received an error message:

> This suggested edit changes too much

[image]

I changed only the title (from "Question is not fully load in iPad" to "Question is not fully loaded on iPad"), not the body of the question. As you can [see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44375), the same edit via the website was submitted successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This edit changed too much"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267864/this-edit-changed-too-much)

Comment: @PatrickHofman The answer there boils down to "Don't change so much, or if you have to change so much use the site." Glorfindel barely changed anything, they wouldn't have easily been able to "not change so much" and did end up going to the site. I'd say the fact that they got the error despite barely changing a thing _is_ a bug, is a separate issue from the proposed question, and means this question should stay open.

Comment: The post is too short.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Would that mean that the linked question somehow barely crossed the line of "non-trivial post" then? _"To combat this, **edits to non-trivial posts** that replace most or all of the content are rejected."_ (emphasis mine) It feels to me like it shouldn't.

Comment: This has been discussed before and I am sure this is the same bug.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was aware of that question, but the workarounds mentioned there don't apply, as I'm barely able to change *less*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next API build, probably early next week.

The problem was that the API was comparing the suggested edit's markdown body the post's HTML body.  This gave every suggested edit and inflated change penalty but this was significantly worse for post with a high Markdown to text ratio, like this post.

In the next build, we will correctly compare the suggested edit's markdown body against the current revision's markdown body.