# "This suggested edit changes too much"

Tags: bug, status-declined, edits, android-app, markdown-preview

When trying to create & preview [this edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/198131) to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/396656/196914) in the Android app (I successfully did it from my computer), I got this error message instead of the preview:

> Please fix the following:
>
> This suggested edit changes too much

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1.

Comment: Can you copy your edited version of that answer into this question?

Comment: @Laurel Is this good?

Comment: Reminds me of [Edit via iOS app - “This suggested edit changes too much”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279211/295232)

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes.

Comment: In the defense of the system, that is a fairly substantial change relative to the length of the answer, but I think it's justified. I don't know if I'd call this a bug though.

Comment: One reason the app may have given you an error but not the website, is that [we don't do this validation for logged in web users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268385/235711).  That said, that change shouldn't have produced that error. Depending on the comment, you could have gotten a different error, but that not that one.  I'll investigate but so far there aren't any red flags.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Why was this declined?

Comment: While this is about the app, from the looks of it, this may also be a problem with the public API, and therefore, supported. Are you sure that that's not the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smells like a version of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279211/295232) to me (thanks Glorfindel for digging it up), though I'm not totally sure. I submitted this to the DAG team's bug triage process and will report back.